# Auto download is not working in firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

Auto download is not working in firefox. Please help me with below code:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();         
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2); //Use for the default download directory the last folder specified for a download
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);       profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in PDF viewer
options.setProfile(profile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: A dublicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949871/selenium-download-file-automatically-c-sharp/51953426#51953426 check my answer there

Comment: I will change MIME according to xlsx. But what about options.addPreference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state",false)

Comment: it is for pdf if need

Comment: So in case of xlsx should I ignore  it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle download pop-up in firefox, while downloading excel using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355204/how-to-handle-download-pop-up-in-firefox-while-downloading-excel-using-selenium)

Comment: In my case when I click "download excel" button, the request gets disappeared immediately from network window. In short its giving me no time to see content type.

Answer (score 0):

For excel try mime:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        .addPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath)
        .addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel,text/xml,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel,application/xhtml+xml,application/octet-stream,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

[How to handle download pop-up in firefox, while downloading excel using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355204/how-to-handle-download-pop-up-in-firefox-while-downloading-excel-using-selenium)

Comment: For xlsx this should be MIME

Comment: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: add `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: I tried your code. however still no luck,its not working.

Comment: FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
          options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
          options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\Downloads");
          options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; application/vnd.ms-excel; text/xml;application/x-excel; application/x-msexcel");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

Comment: You have to find mime type somehow. Try to add `application/xhtml+xml,application/octet-stream`

Comment: Thanks, after adding above MIME its working.Is there any way to get MIME of a file in one go ??

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer for other people. You can close than

Answer (score 0):

to be more precise MIME that worked for me for automating download of xlsx file through firefox is "application/octet-stream".