# Which MIME type for setting firefox Preference to automatically download .ebc file?

Tags: java, html, selenium, firefox, automation

I am trying to download one file with extension .ebc (EBC File) in selenium Automation.

```
<a href="sample.ebc">sample.ebc</a>
```

I have tried below written Preferences, it is working for .Zip file or text file, but for .ebc file it is still giving me popup for save and openWith.

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Users\\userName\\Downloads");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/x-ebc*,text/ebc,text/EBC,application/EBC,application/octet-stream,text/html, text/plain");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/x-ebc*,text/ebc,text/EBC,application/EBC,application/octet-stream,text/html, text/plain");
```

Thanks in Advance.
P.S: Don't want to use Robot Class or AutoIT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309314/set-firefox-profile-to-download-files-automatically-using-selenium-and-java

Comment: @sers - Hey man!! many many Thanks. It works!
Got MIME TYpe- "text/ebcdic"  :D :D