# Selenium blocking downloads with Edge?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have a web automation tool developed with Python and Selenium and using the MS Edge driver.  All is working well except when downloading a file.  The message "Couldn't download - blocked" appears in the Downloads window.

I've tested this same case with a user-launched instance of Edge and it works fine.  So I'm guessing the selenium launched instance of Edge has some restriction applied to it.  Not sure how to approach this?

Environment:
Windows 10 Enterprise 19044.2486 (no admin access)
Selenium:  4.1.3
Edge:  Version 109.0.1518.61 (Official build) (64-bit)
Msedgedriver.exe:  109.0.1518.52
Python.exe:  3.10.4150.1013

Comment: Could you please show us how you download the file? Is it a simple click or did you use any Edge option? Also, minimal code to reproduce is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will try yo use the capabilities of Edge to allow the downloads.

As the options and capabilities are the same as Chrome browser. You have some options in this other answer, focusing on:

> browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk

> pdfjs.disabled

> browser.download.viewableInternally.enabledTypes

[Set Firefox profile to download files automatically using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309314/set-firefox-profile-to-download-files-automatically-using-selenium-and-java)